# Lazy loading not working in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two classes that are connected by using the virtual keyword:

Student:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId{get; set;}
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}
```

Enrollment:

```
public class Enrollment
{
    public int EnrollmentId { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public decimal? Grade { get; set; }
    public virtual Course course { get; set; }
    public virtual Student student { get; set; }
}
```

Both tables are populated, and have corresponding records (for instance, there is a student with id 1 and enrollments for student with id 1).

I'm pulling up a student by it's id and sending it to a view

```
Student student = db.Students.Find(id);
return View(student);
```

In the view I can display the details for that student. The `@Model` does contain an `Enrollment` property (at least it comes up in intellisense and doesn't red-line), but it is `Null`.

There is also a course class:

```
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public String CourseName { get; set; }
    public int TotalCredits { get; set; }
}
```

Since `@Model.Enrollments` is `Null`, I can't access `@Model.Enrollment.CourseNamae`.

**Edit:**
I just tried a hack workaround:

```
IEnumerable<Student> temp = db.Students.Include(s => s.Enrollments);
Student student = temp.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StudentId.Equals(id));
return View(student);
```

This is giving me the error on the second line:

> System.InvalidOperationException: A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'MyFirstProject2.Models.Student' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Enrollments'.

Does that offer any clues?

Comment: Try eager-loading the `Enrollment` (i.e. `db.Students.Include(s => s.Enrollments).Find(id);`)

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, what I was doing is apparently called "lazy loading."

Comment: I'm getting `Error 1 'System.Linq.IQueryable<MyFirstProject2.Models.Student>' does not contain a definition for 'Find' and no extension method 'Find' accepting a first argument of type`.  I'm working through a tutorial, and they are trying to demonstrate lazy loading, but I'd be happy to just have it work.

Comment: You need to add `using System.Data.Entity;` to the top of your class. The `.Include` is an extension method.

Comment: It's got that, and has no trouble finding `.Include`. For instance, I can do `IEnumerable<Student> temp = db.Students.Include(s => s.Enrollments);` to get a list of students. But then I would need to use a find method for `IEnumerable`, which I can do, but seems like I should be able to get at least one of the eager or lazy loading schemes to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little bit late but here some explanation between [Lazy Loading vs Eager Loading](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/entityframework/RIWW210913-Difference-between-Lazy-Loading-and-Eager-Loading.html)

**And also the Rules for lazy loading**:

1. context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled should be true.
2. context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled should be true.
3. Navigation property should be defined as public, virtual. Context will NOT do lazy loading if the property is not define as
   virtual.

**EDIT**:
One last thing for relationships use:

```
public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
```

Other Links:

[Lazy Loading](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/lazy-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx)

[Eager Loading](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/eager-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx)

[Explicit Loading](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/explicit-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. After the comment about eager loading, I went out and read a little about the differences. However, my problem is that it isn't working. I'm going through video tutorials, and I went back through like four times, and I'm pretty sure I have all the code correct. The loading just isn't happening -- the Enrollments property is null. Does my code give any clues as to why?

Comment: Wait, I did not pay attention to the edit (or we crossed). That was it. Now I need to read about the difference between `ICollection` and `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @abalter glad to help, I use EF as a daily DB access technology, but you have to research a lot; dont worry its a really cool framework to access DBs and  relationships take a while to understand.